# Map C++ structure with std::vector to C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll

In C++ Dll I have this code:

```
struct Bar 
{
   std::vector<double> a;
   std::vector<double> b;
}

std::vector<Bar> t;
```

How can I map `t` to be accesible from C#.

For example, I have created this in C++ Dll

```
__declspec(dllexport) void ReleaseNet(std::vector<Bar> t)
{
    someObject.setData(t);
};
```

And from C# I need to pass data to this method.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether microsoft has some kind of mapping for STL containers but generally, using STL on the api boundary is a big "no no" since your vector class might have a different size on the other side. (an example is where visual studio in debug adds a bit of data to the structure for debug purpose)

if all you want to map is a vector, then one sure thing is that a vector is a contiguous block of memory. So you could sort of treat it as an array.

[Passing vector struct between C++ and C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15466290/passing-vector-struct-between-c-and-c-sharp) this gives you a bit more insight.